# Making out the meaning of words

Tags: meaning, slang, phrase-meaning

I am listening to a story that has no transcript. So I can’t make out some phrases and therefore the meaning of some sentences. I would really appreciate if you could help me out;) thanks in advance!

1. The town where my whole family is, the town I grew up in, the town I took acid and **talked to hoodies** in.
2. I went to drama school for 3 years. I pretended to be **steam**. Knowing that my dad, the man who raised me, doesn’t love me the way I live him.
3. And we are standing outside the funeral home. You are not meant to be **the pull and bear** for your family. But for some reason, nonno wanted us to carry him for the last time.

Here is the link to the story: 
https://player.themoth.org/#/?actionType=ADD_AND_PLAY&storyId=14403

It’s from 2:50 min

Comment: If it's audio, you could still provide a link to the source.

Comment: @Kris I added a link to the story, Hope it’s going to help)

Comment: This is a great question and a much needed expansion of ELU into spoken language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the audio, your questions are impossible to answer with certainty. However, "be the pull and bear", is almost certainly, given the context, "be the pallbearer" (i.e., the carrier of the coffin). The words "talked to hoddiesin", might well be "talked to hoodies in" (i.e., in which I talked to young people wearing [hoodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoodie), the word being applicable both to the wearer of a hoodie and the garment itself. As for the second phrase, "I pretended to be steam", I have no idea.

If you post a link to the audio, as suggested in the comment, a more accurate answer would be forthcoming!

Addition: I have listened to the audio. and can add the following. You heard the words "Talked to hoodies in" correctly. I accept the comment that "hoodie" has an old meaning of "a person in the neighbourhood" in some regions. However, the speaker is an Australian, and the Macquarie Dictionary of Australian English does not record that meaning as having been current in Australia, so my suggestion that the speaker is referring to young people wearing hoodies gains credence. You heard "pretended to be steam" correctly. It sounds as if the speaker is parodying the kind of things that happen in drama school. And finally, "pallbearer" is the correct rendition of the third expression.

Comment: Actually, "hoodie", meaning someone from the neighborhood, goes back decades earlier than the meaning of "hooded sweatshirt".

Comment: @HotLicks the speaker is Australian, not American, and I can attest that no Australian uses "hoodie" to mean "from the 'hood" (no-one here uses that expression either), it just means the hooded top (and by implication the wearer thereof).

Comment: @user02814 +1, although it's funny to read someone giving an answer based on best guess rather than local knowledge! The talk is perfectly intelligible to an Aussie: *hoodies* are stereotypically unemployed, socially disadvantaged youth; *pretended to be steam* is indeed a parody of the practice in drama classes of acting an interpretation of inanimate objects like trees, clouds or in this case water vapour; and yes, *pallbearers*.